# Batch split wave files from markers

Tags: audio, batch, adobe

I have several thousand wave files which I'd like to split into tracks. I plan to add markers with Audition CC, then split them into individual wave files and convert to FLAC, but Audition won't split files as a batch (running this operation on multiple *files* at a time, not simply splitting one file into its constituent regions.)

Windows solutions would be preferable to Mac/Unix, and I'm willing to purchase software if necessary. I've considered rolling my own with Python but I'd prefer a GUI and I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if this problem has been elegantly solved in the past.

Thanks!

Edit: Might go with [TwistedWave](https://twistedwave.com/), a $79 Mac app, though I'd have to run it through GigE on my MacBook Air, rather than directly on my i5 PC.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ProTools software. Just use the strip silence tool to remove the silence between the sounds. Then ProTools will put all your snipers into your Region list. Then you simply need to collect all audio files in the Region list and press Export Regions as Files. Then you can decide in which Format and at wich Location to bounce.

Hope this helps!
Good Day

Comment: Thanks, Tobias. Would this be possible as a batch in Pro Tools? (select multiple wave files, each containing several markers, and split them all, perhaps using a serial suffix following each original filename)  
  
Edit: Apparently this is possible in TwistedWave, a $80 Mac app. Might go with this but I'd prefer to handle it on my Win7 workstation.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Audition can do exactly what you want!

In the Edit view, go to `Window` -> `Marker list` (Alt-8)
Select the marker regions you want.
At the bottom there's an icon that looks like a save button (I added a red circle around it):

[image]

As you can see from the screen-shot, you can save them as individual FLAC files.

Comment: Thanks, Louis. I've edited my question to clarify, but I'm aware of this capability. I'd like to run this operation on multiple *files* at a time, not simply splitting one file at a time into its constituent regions.

Comment: I tried to create a script in Audition to do it, but you are correct. Audition does not allow saving actions to be part of a script, so the actions like saving all markers are left out of macro's. It could be done with an [external macro recording tool](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools/creating-automated-tests/automated-test-recording-engine/) (usually used for automated GUI testing), but that would be allot more work, probably not worth processing just one batch of files.

Comment: Yeah... I was thinking about AutoIT as well, but you're right about the hassle of writing, configuring, testing an automation script. TwistedWave it is!